# How to correctly insert a JavaScript variable into a custom tracking pixel?

Tags: javascript, tracking

I have a JavaScript variable declared higher in my page as

`var transactionID = XX` (XX is just a placeholder)

I need to insert this variable into a tracking pixel supplied by an affliate partner of ours, but I am unsure of how you would write this into the pixel.

Below is the pixel which is placed at the bottom of the `<body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ad.domain.com/ppl/?15333C2049059826&mode=[[1]]&CustomerID=[[1]]&OrderID=[[]]&PartnerID=[[]]"> </script>
```

I have been told by the suppliers of this code that anything entered within the `[[]]` will be a static value. E.g. `CustomerID=[[1]]` - In this case, the value will be set to 1. And that is fine.

But for the case of `OrderID=[[]]`, I want to set it to insert a JavaScript variable e.g. `transactionID`

Can you please help me understand the correct way to write this with JavaScript into the pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use document.write but be SURE to escape the end slash /

```
<script>
     document.write('<script src="https://ad.domain.com/ppl/?15333C2049059826' + 
         '&mode=[[1]]&CustomerID=[[1]]&OrderID=[[' + transactionID + ']]' +
         '&PartnerID=[[]]"></' + 'script>');
</script>
```

Comment: Escaping the slash `\/` as I suggested is also OK

Comment: Thank you very much Patrik! Worked liked a dream :)